# Great expectation error when using save_expectations_config() function

Tags: python, great-expectations

I tried to run this code using PyCharm:

```py
import great_expectations as ge
df=ge.read_csv(r"C:\Users\TasbeehJ\data\yellow_tripdata_2019-01.csv")
print(df.expect_column_values_to_be_in_set('passenger_count',[1,2,3,4,5]))

conf=df.get_expectation_suite()

df.save_expectations_config(r"C:\Users\TasbeehJ\data\yellow_tripdata_2019-01.data.expectations.json")
```

but it gave me this error:

> AttributeError: 'PandasDataset' object has no attribute 'save_expectations_config'

how can I save the config if not using that??

Comment: What makes you think `save_expectations_config` should exist…?

Comment: I watched this, they used it and it worked!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_0tG7ACNU4

Comment: It's entirely possible the library has been refactored in those intervening 4 years. Try basing your code on the current documentation first…

Answer (score 2):

The ***save_expectations_config*** has been refactored to ***save_expectation_suite***.